# why can't the following mutex be shared by multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

Considering the following code:

```rust
    pub fn with_lock<T>(f: &dyn Fn(&mut Connection) -> T) -> T {
        let mut guard = Connection::mutex().lock().unwrap();
        let re = f(&mut *guard);
        re
    }

    pub fn start() -> Result<()> {
        let fusion = Arc::new(any_fusion()?);
        let fusion_clone = Arc::clone(&fusion);
        let fusion_m = Mutex::new(fusion_clone);

        let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
            // Task to be executed in the new thread
            loop {
                fusion_m.lock().unwrap().update();
            }
        });

        Self::with_lock(&|c| {
            c.fusion = Some(*fusion);
            c.thread = Some(handle);
        });

        Ok(())
    }
```

When compiling, I have the following error:

```
error[E0277]: `dyn Fusion` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src/lib.rs:189:36
    |
189 |           let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
    |  ______________________-------------_^
    | |                      |
    | |                      required by a bound introduced by this call
190 | |             // Task to be executed in the new thread
191 | |             loop {
192 | |                 fusion_m.lock().unwrap().update();
193 | |             }
194 | |         });
    | |_________^ `dyn Fusion` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn Fusion`
    = note: required for `Unique<dyn Fusion>` to implement `Sync`
```

this error is strange, as none of the variable used in the spawn closure has the type `dyn Fusion`, the only relevant variable `fusion_m` has the type `Mutex<Arc<dyn Fusion>` returned by `any_fusion()`, which should always be safe for synchronous access.

What's the cause of this error and how to make the compiler recognise the type of `fusion_m` properly?

Comment: If `Fusion` is a trait then `Arc<Fusion>` actually means `Arc<dyn Fusion>` and in fact the `dyn` syntax is required in non-ancient versions of Rust, so I'm very curious how you're compiling this.

Comment: `Arc<Mutex<_>>` has a static lifetime, and can be used with `thread::spawn`. `Mutex<Arc<_>>` only lives for the scope.

Comment: @cdhowie ahh sorry I mean Mutex<Arc<dyn Fusion>> (wasn't aware that dyn was part of the type signature), corrected now

Comment: @PitaJ that sounds likely, but in this case I was expecting the compiler giving a different error message

Comment: It looks like `dyn Fusion + Sync + Send` might satisfy the compiler, but `Mutex<Arc<T>>` doesn't give you mutable access to `T` anyway, so it's very likely that you do want `Arc<Mutex<T>>`. If you use `Arc<Mutex<T>>` then I think you just need `dyn Fusion + Send` (`Mutex` will "add" `Sync`-ness to the type if it's `Send`).

Comment: thanks a lot I'll try Arc<Mutex<T>> this is still strange, as Mutex<T> works in mutli-threading

Comment: `Mutex` works for multi-threading _if you use it correctly_, like pretty much everything else.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I mean, Mutex<T> works even if T is a subtype of Send but not Sync.

Comment: Yes, but `Arc` requires `Sync` to be `Send`, and `dyn Fusion` is neither `Sync` nor `Send`.